# Why mouse zoom in,out not working on icloud.com find my iphon?

Tags: icloud, find-my-iphone

I am using Linux Ubuntu. When trying to use www.icloud.com/#find any mouse movements like zoom or scroll not working.

Any solutions?

Comment: More detail might help - what mouse movements? Clicking the +/- signs? dragging the map?

Comment: Clicking to -/+ works. I wonder why can not we zoom in or zoom out with mouse?

Comment: I don't think it's designed to. Google Maps does, Apple's doesn't [at least not on that page]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest you use the +/- buttons on the upper left. At the time of posting, there is no mouse-input way to zoom the map in or out.

I tested it on Safari on a Mac with Yosemite (10.10).

[image: iCloud Find my iPhone]

Comment: I am asking why there is no mouse input?

Comment: @akikara, As with all websites, that is an option that is left entirely to the developer(s) thereof. They would have to write the script to handle that.

Comment: Fare enough but not satisfied. I will ask this to Apple. Thanks for your answer. Still I think there should be.